# tmux windows in iTerm2 keep on snapping to 54x31 characters

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I am running iTerm2 v3.4.18, connecting to tmux 3.3a on CentOS 7.9.

I regularly open new windows in my session using `tmux new-window` (usually to run vim in it).  Frequently (I think more frequently after I've been manipulating panes with mouse) opening a new window snaps it to 54 columns by 31 lines.  This also sometimes happens when using iTerm to open a new window.

Also, if I drag a VIM pane by the tab in iTerm2 window (commonly what happens when I'm just moving the iTerm2 window), the window frequently resizes on end of drag, snapping to 54 columns by 31 lines.

I cannot figure out why this is happening or how to stop it.  How do I fix this?

(Question moved here from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74787486/1663427) per [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162698/rob)'s suggestion)

Comment: linked stackoverflow link is dead

Comment: Original post was identical to this one. I was asked to move it here and delete original. The deleted original is still in the database - I need to logon to have the link work. I don’t know if others logged in can see it too.